# How to identify touch on UIView subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a scrollview. Inside the scrollview, I have three subviews, A, B, C. When I click on subview A, I want to get either its tag value or know which view I've clicked. I've gone through many codes and blogs, but couldn't find a solution for it.

```
    - (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {}
    - (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event{} //This function is not working with sub view.
```

Tried these methods but didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Add a tap gesture recognizer to each of A, B, C views, set the delegate to the view controller and you will be notified on each tap.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* tgrA = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[viewA addGestureRecognizer:tgrA];
...

-(void) handleTapGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender 
{
    //sender.view.tag will give you what you need.
}
```

More information on tap gesture recognizer here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html